# Next.js with App Router, server-side code failing to build with node.js deps when using Turborepo

Tags: next.js, vercel, firebase-admin, turborepo, app-router

I am migrating my existing Next.js projects to a Turborepo monorepo.

The Next.js projects use the newest App Router, and have server-side routes and components which previously all successfully built outside of Turborepo, but now fail to build seemingly because they're seen as client code and they are loading server-side node modules (primarily `firebase-admin`). None of my dependencies in package.json have changed versions.

Here's an example page that should be regarded as [server component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#server-components). `/src/app/example/[document_id]/page.js`:

```
import { db } from "@/app/api/firebase-admin"
// import components

export default async function Page({ params: { document_id } }) {
    const docSnapshot = await db.collection('docs').doc(document_id).get();
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        const data = docSnapshot.data();
        return <Document {...data} />
    }
    return <NotFound />
}
```

The above code builds perfectly in a standalone Next.js project, but in Turborepo complains about things like `Can't resolve 'fs' in @google/cloud/...` which makes me think that it's trying to pack the server side modules for the client bundle.

Any help solving this issue is much appreciated.

---

EDIT: Wanted to mention here that my project is structured according to the standard, same as the example [here](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/blob/main/examples/basic/turbo.json)

Answer (score 1):

From What I see in the [turborepo code here](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/blob/main/examples/basic/turbo.json)
You might need to have Turbo set up 1 level above your next project and let turborepo do its job of caching and bundling from there.
As seen in [line 6](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/blob/5ab8ac047a23ce7c066c7c054fcaffc7a914cada/examples/basic/turbo.json#L6)
It explicitly mentions that the build for the turbo repo depends on an existing nextjs build.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately this is not the solution since my project already is structured that way... I'll add that information to my question